Django: Select multiple random ids and insert to database
I'm generating schedules and it will automatically choose from RoutePoint class. I wanted to POST all these ids and create # of rows based on how many id's the user wants.
This is how I select random ids. But it shows RoutePoints object (3)
no_of_route = request.POST.get('time')

items = list(RoutePoints.objects.all())
random_route = random.sample(items, no_of_route)[0]

So the problem is, I don't know how to insert these ids. Like bulk insert? If the user choose 3 no_of_route, there should be 3 rows inserted to 'Schedule' table.
Schedule.objects.create(route=random_route, report_time=report_time)

This is my first time, so I'm not sure how to do it exactly. Thank you for your help.
